# Show hint near the action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock. When longpressing the action bar icon, a hint appears near that icon. How do I invoke the display of such hint near the action bar with custom text manually?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to get the Menu Item from the ID in your action bar menu xml file and then manually set an on long click listener which would override the default.

```
MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)R.menu.my_action_menu;
menuItem.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener)
public OnLongClickListener nOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener()
{
      //Add required methods and display toast here
}
```

I can't remember the exact code at the top of my head but hopefully the code above may help.